# How to start a java program?

Tags: java, user-interface

I have written a java program and I am running it through command line like "java MyProgram"

Now I want to have a GUI that have a start, pause and stop button. How to start that java program by clicking on start button. How to pause it and how to stop it?

Answer (score 4):

I assume your program is something like:

```
public class MyProgram {

  public void doSomething() {
    // ... does something ...
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MyProgram().doSomething();
  }
}
```

I recommend reading the [Swing Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/), but a simple GUI to launch your program could be something like:

```
public class MyProgramLauncher {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final MyProgram myProgram = new MyProgram();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Program");
    JComponent cp = frame.getContentPane();
    cp.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Start") {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        myProgram.doSomething();
      }
    }));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

If your class has a `pause()` function, you could add a similar `JButton` to call that function, but you'd have to write/implement the function.

You would, however, have to launch this with `java MyProgramLauncher`, which isn't very exciting. Still, that will get you a basic GUI in which you can experiment with starting, pausing, etc.

To turn your program into something you can double-click on, you'll need to create a [JAR file](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html). This is basically a special ZIP file that includes all the classes in your application, plus a `manifest.xml` file that describes those classes and (for launchable JAR files) identifies the "main class" whose `main()` method should be called when the JAR file is launched.

To turn that JAR file into a more or less self-contained deployable application is a bigger pain and there are a whole lot of options. The [Deployment Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/index.html) might be a place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need a native launcher, but I cannot figure out what do you mean exactly by "pause"... Sending the process to sleep?

I think that should be very easy to implement with a shellscript using the xdialog command in a Unix like system.

You'll need to implement a state machine:

- State: "Stopped"

  - Start: execute java YourProgram and store the PID in a variable. Change state to "Started"
  - Pause: do nothing/disabled
  - Stop: do nothing/disabled
- State: "Started"

  - Start: do nothing/disabled
  - Pause: send the STOP signal (like ctr+z) to the process. Change state to "Paused"
  - Stop: send the INT signal (like ctr+c) to the process. Change state to "Stopped"
- State "Paused"

  - Start: do nothing/disabled
  - Pause: send the CONT signal (like doing fg) to the process. Change start to "Started"
  - Stop: send the INT signal (like ctr+c) to the process. Change state to "Stopped"

With this, you can loop in the script and react to the buttons. Look the reference for **kill** and **dialog** or xdialog for more details on the implementation.

Comment: A native launcher isn't necessary. A executable .jar works just fine and doesn't artificially restrict the platform compatibility.

Comment: but it doesn't have buttons, just starts the application... he needs something graphical -to launch- (not after it's already launched) his application, right?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to write your "Forms"...

This will be a helpful resource to a beginner.

[Basics](http://www.csis.pace.edu/~bergin/sol/java/gui/)